# Xcode - No provisioned iOS device is connected

Tags: iphone, xcode

I was using Xcode this afternoon and debugging an app on my device just fine.  When I got home from the office and plugged in my phone to keep working, XCode would no longer let me debug on my device.  The error I received was:

```
Error Starting Executable.  No provisioned iOS device is connected.
```

So I hopped over to the Organizer, and here is what I saw:

[image]

So what gives?  Anyone seen this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Try killing the app in question, or rebooting your device, or restarting Xcode. Any luck?

Comment: Nope... Restarted computer and device and no luck.  Maybe if I delete and reinstall the SDK? But how would I do that?  Is that even the right thing to do? growl.

Comment: The usual suspects...have you tried right-clicking on your device and selecting "Use for developing" (or something similar, don't remember)?  Also, it could be a provisioning profile problem, try redoing your certificate and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @WrightsCS: Congrats on your first 2k-rep edit :)

Comment: Had the same issues on my device...
possibly caused by an upgrade to iOS 5 BETA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't know why this helped, but if anyone else sees this thread the thing that "fixed" the problem was to remove the SDK from my machine, restart XCode, then plug in the device.  XCode then popped up an alert view asking to collect the debugging symbols from the device, which I allowed it to do.  From then on it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You may be testing your application on simulator and accidentally, device is selected instead of simulator. It help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have upgraded to the latest Xcode 3.2.5 with iOSK 4.2.1 SDK.

Comment: If he hadn't, "Latest" wouldn't be in that list I think.

Comment: Possibly. Maybe the provisioning profiles are expired on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

I had another way of fixing this problem.

I tried upgrading my device to iOS5 Beta 7 ...to test my app in iOS5
Once i finished testing it, wanted to get back to iOS4.3.5 on my device...

it took a little pain but managed to restore it back to the original 
but then the debugging didn't work and got the same error as mentioned here.

So i wanted to see what i see in that snapshot that you have : and there it was...
A button called "enable for debugging" if i'm not mistaken.

Worked like a charm.... :)